# RedirectMatch file not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, I have in my web root an admin.php file and I want every time someone writes /admin to be redirected to that /admin.php.

I wrote in my htaccess

> RedirectMatch 301 ^/admin$ /admin.php

However, I get an error from apache "file not found".

I created an empty /admin folder and it works...

---

Then I try to have an other (also non existant folder) to redirect to admin.php. So I write

> RedirectMatch 301 ^/blah$ /admin.php

and it works...

---

Finally I delete the admin.php and I have the thing redirected to another .php

> RedirectMatch 301 ^/admin$ /index.php

and it works again...

---

I understand that for some reason apache messes things up when the folder to be redirected from has the same name with the .php

With Rewrite I can do the redirection without any problems but I was wondering if it was also possible with just a Redirect... Maybe I am missing something here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> apache messes things up when the folder to be redirected from has the same name with the .php

This is due to **Apache's content negotiation module** that runs before `mod_rewrite`, `mod_alias` and makes Apache web server match extensions of files. e.g. `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

To fix this behavior **disable** `MultiViews` by placing this rule on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: hey anubhava i want to chat with you for a while on htaccess please help me